# Power bi deleting rows and keeping first row

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I imported a table from SQL which is more than 100k rows. i was connecting it to data model
but then i found that it has some duplicate rows. i identified those duplicate rows which are

[image]

they repeating twice i want to keep first and delete whole second copy of them. i tried for hours in query editor adding custom column but it just would let me add new column condition as data view in power bi did.

Answer (score 0):

Edited: Group, and find the first occurrence, like here

```
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"PriorStepNameHere", {"TestColumn1","TestColumn2"}, {{"data", each Table.RemoveColumns(Table.AddColumn(Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type), "First Instance?", each if [Index]=0 then 1 else 0),{"Index"}), type table }}),
```

then expand

Comment: yes i want to manually filter out the repeated and remove myself

Comment: edited answer to manually tag first instance

Answer (score 0):

Hope, you'll get a better solution form SO contributors, if not you can try like this.

```
let
Source=...
filtered = 
    Table.RemoveMatchingRows(
        Source
        ,{[Keycode= "qwe123", Desc="rty456"]}
        ,"Desc"
    )
in
filtered
```